# How to check if a webpage is loaded or not in the browser window,when redirecting from a different website?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser

My requirement is that I have a few hyperlinks on a webpage and when the user clicks on these hyperlinks I should redirect the user to an asp.net web page(Default.aspx) in a different website.

For the 1st time when the user clicks on one of the hyperlinks it will launch a new browser window with the Default.aspx loaded and then if the user clicks on some other hyperlink I want to redirect the user to the existing browser window(in which deafult.aspx is already loaded)with the content related to this particular hyperlink loaded,instead of launching a new browser window/tab.

But I am not sure of how to achieve this.I wonder if I can add some js to the asp.net Default.aspx page to achieve this.

Please could someone put me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the `target` property of the `<a>` tag will serve your purposes.  Try:

```
<a href="http://somedomain.com/default.aspx" target="unique_name1">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://someotherdomain.com/default.aspx" target="unique_name2">Link 2</a>
```

Any clicks on the link subsequent to the first one should not result in additional windows.